# What to answer for "Regular additional income you get in a year" and "how much money in savings (GBP)" for UK tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, applications

I am planning to visit the UK as part of a tour group. My UK visa was rejected due to an incorrect amount written for "Total amount of additional income you get in a year".

I'm planning on reapplying and will write the following amount for the questions:

1. "Total amount of regular additional income that you get in a year?"

   answer: My actual income as stated in my ITR.
2. "How much money do you have in savings (in GBP)?"

   answer: I will add my FD + Government bonds + money in my savings account.

All the relevant proof of the above will be submitted as well.

Is this the correct approach? I'm a housewife and unemployed, and will sponsor the trip with my own money.

Any guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: ‘Unemployed’ sounds like a potential (big) red flag as far as intention to leave the UK is concerned. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab